# Does MEK-toluene system create a negative deviation from Raoult's law?

Tags: physical-chemistry

From the experimental data obtained in our lab, when pressure is plotted against mol fraction and partial pressure, it exhibits a negative deviation from Raoult's law which must mean that the forces between MEK and toluene are attractive. But all the info I've found on the internet says that the deviation is positive.

Is MEK soluble in toluene? And could you please give me chemically similar systems.

Comment: Are you saying that there is literature data that differs from you own experimental data?